# Change default Login page in FOSUserBundle (Symfony)

Tags: php, security, symfony, fosuserbundle

I think that both the question and the answer here shouldn't be very complicated.

I have installed and configured the FOSUserBundle to use in a project with Symfony2.

What I need to know is where I tell the Security which page it has to redirect the user when they try to access to a forbidden url.

By default it is /login. But I'd like to change it to a more general /main.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9):

It's not done by FOSUserBundle, but the Security system in Symfony2. You need to set the following in security.yml:

```
firewalls:
    main:
        form_login:
            default_target_path: /path/to/redirect/to
```

EDIT:

Sorry, misread the question. Change login_path to /admin like so:

```
firewalls:
    main:
        form_login:
            login_path: /admin
```

This will redirect you to the /admin page - make sure the path works and isn't protected by the firewall. More info [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#the-login-form-and-process).

Comment: Thank you, but I already had tried that and that is not what I am looking for. That is to tell the engine where to go once logged-in. I need to configure (o customize) de url where I am redirected when I try to access a page from the secured area before I am validated.

Comment: your mistake was helpful because that is what I needed ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok

I got it!

It was more like:

```
        main:
        form_login:
            login_path: /path/to/redirect/to
```

Thanks again

Comment: @VitaliyZurian Seconded!