# Symfony 2 path if unauthorized

Tags: symfony, authentication, configuration

My problem is. If user goes to path A which has security restrictions and user has to login, he gets redirected to login path. How can i change this to redirect to other url. For example root path.

Comment: Do you use fos_user bundle?

Comment: @greg606 yes, i do. I have thought doing some workaround and redirect if form is not loaded with ajax (I use login form as ajax form), but that seemed like hacky thing to do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819547/change-default-login-page-in-fosuserbundle-symfony

Comment: Almoust, but the login_failure handler is ment for handling scenario when credentials are bad. I tryed to fix solution to work, but it ended as hacky as the other solution.

Comment: What do you mean? You don't mention anything about bad credentails in your question.